# Is it possible to reduce the size of an image comes from byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a byte array that contains a jpeg image. I was just wondering if it is possible to reduce its size?

Edit: Ok. I acknowledged my mistake. Then my question is how can I reduce the quality of the image comes from a byte array.

Comment: What do you mean? An array has a fixed size once it's created, but are you talking about image compression? Reducing the quality? Reducing the image size? Please clarify.

Comment: slicing it off like a pizza and eat it. sorry byte arrays remind me of pizzas. especially circular buffer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please understand that there is no free lunch. Decreasing the size of a JPEG image by increasing the compression will also decrease the quality of the image. However, that said, you can reduce the size of a JPEG image using the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7e7b2kd.aspx) class. This code assumes that `inputBytes` contains the original image.

```
var jpegQuality = 50; 
Image image; 
using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(inputBytes)) {
  image = Image.FromStream(inputStream);
  var jpegEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders() 
    .First(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid); 
  var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1); 
  encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, jpegQuality); 
  Byte[] outputBytes; 
  using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream()) { 
    image.Save(outputStream, jpegEncoder, encoderParameters);
    outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray(); 
  } 
}
```

Now `outputBytes` contains a recompressed version of the image using a different JPEG quality.

By decreasing the `jpegQuality` (should be in the range 0-100) you can increase the compression at the cost of lower image quality. See the [`Encoder.Quality`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.quality.aspx) field for more information.

Here is an example where you can see how `jpegQuality` affects the image quality. It is the same photo compressed using 20, 50 and 80 as the value of `jpegQuality`. Sizes are 4.99, 8.28 and 12.9 KB.

[image: JPEG quality sample image]

Notice how the text becomes "smudged" even when the quality is high. This is why you should avoid using JPEG for images with uniformly colored areas (images/diagrams/charts created on a computer). Use PNG instead. For photos JPEG is very suitable if you do not lower the quality too much.

Comment: A generic error occurred in GDI+. :(

in this line: `image.Save(memoryStream, jpegEncoder, encoderParameters);`

Comment: @MehmetBudak: Sorry, fixed the code. (The `Image` class is "lazy" and accesses the image bytes as late as possible. Previously, I disposed the input buffer too early.)

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
// Create a thumbnail in byte array format from the image encoded in the passed byte array.  
// (RESIZE an image in a byte[] variable.)  
public static byte[] CreateThumbnail(byte[] PassedImage, int LargestSide)  
{  
    byte[] ReturnedThumbnail;  

    using (MemoryStream StartMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(),  
                        NewMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())  
    {  
        // write the string to the stream  
        StartMemoryStream.Write(PassedImage, 0, PassedImage.Length);  

        // create the start Bitmap from the MemoryStream that contains the image  
        Bitmap startBitmap = new Bitmap(StartMemoryStream);  

        // set thumbnail height and width proportional to the original image.  
        int newHeight;  
        int newWidth;  
        double HW_ratio;  
        if (startBitmap.Height > startBitmap.Width)  
        {  
            newHeight = LargestSide;  
            HW_ratio = (double)((double)LargestSide / (double)startBitmap.Height);  
            newWidth = (int)(HW_ratio * (double)startBitmap.Width);  
        }  
        else 
        {  
            newWidth = LargestSide;  
            HW_ratio = (double)((double)LargestSide / (double)startBitmap.Width);  
            newHeight = (int)(HW_ratio * (double)startBitmap.Height);  
        }  

        // create a new Bitmap with dimensions for the thumbnail.  
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);  

        // Copy the image from the START Bitmap into the NEW Bitmap.  
        // This will create a thumnail size of the same image.  
        newBitmap = ResizeImage(startBitmap, newWidth, newHeight);  

        // Save this image to the specified stream in the specified format.  
        newBitmap.Save(NewMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);  

        // Fill the byte[] for the thumbnail from the new MemoryStream.  
        ReturnedThumbnail = NewMemoryStream.ToArray();  
    }  

    // return the resized image as a string of bytes.  
    return ReturnedThumbnail;  
}  

// Resize a Bitmap  
private static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image, int width, int height)  
{  
    Bitmap resizedImage = new Bitmap(width, height);  
    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))  
    {  
        gfx.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),   
            new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);  
    }  
    return resizedImage;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The byte array size can always be reduced but you will lose data about your image.  You could reduce the quality of the jpeg then it would take up less data as a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the JPEG bytes as being a very compressed representation of a much larger number of bytes.
So if you try to apply some function to reduce the number of bytes it would be like trying to compress an already compressed thing.